# populate dropdown with list of spoken languages

Tags: drop-down-menu

I want to create a dropdown list with a list of spoken languages (English, Arabic, French, Spanish, etc.).  Any idea where to get a full list?  I will import the list into a database and then bind using a sql query ...

Comment: Are you only interested in a list of the languages (as provided in one of the answers) or are you looking for help with the technical implementation?

Comment: If you want to do it programatically and make use of the Microsoft List of languages with their own Ids to prevent the need to use your own table, I have provided an answer with the solution.

Comment: What server and programming language are you using?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will give you a list of string names of languages you can then assign to the ComboBox, or you can replace languageList.Add() with ComboBox.Items.Add().

```
public static List<string> GetCountryList()
{

    List<string> languageList = new List<string>();
    CultureInfo[] cultureList = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures);

    foreach (CultureInfo culture in cultureList)
    {
        languageList.Add(culture.DisplayName);
    }
    return languageList;
}
```

Or you can do the following:

```
    CultureInfo[] cultures = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures);

    ComboBox b = new ComboBox();
    b.DisplayMember = "DisplayName";
    b.ValueMember = "LCID";
    b.DataSource = cultures;
```

Comment: I must be missing something - the question doesn't mention a programming language, the only tag is "drop-down-menu", and you also don't do it, still, the code is in C#? This is specific to C# and doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

[List of Languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lists_of_languages)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about a canonical source (or whether it's even possible to generate one), but [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_languages_by_number_of_native_speakers) has a fairly long list, ordered by usage.  The article has links to other lists (top 100, top 30, etc).